# Avocado tree to skinny

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, watering

What can I do to make it fuller Avocado tree. About 4 months old Only 3 leaves 21” tall. Already pinched back 2 times. South facing window indoors daytime diffused light. Direct sun  one day burnt 2 leaves.  8 inch pot, regular potting soil. Never been fertilized water two times weekly

Comment: Please post a photo of it.

Answer (score 0):

Avocado are not really suitable for small pots, the bigger the pot and the higher you pack in the soil the better.

Comment: So I should have the seed fully covered now